# Not Understanding VisionEncoderDecoder Pixel Value Shape after call model.generate

Tags: pytorch

I am very new to PyTorch and have been playing around with OCR. Here is me trying to load my model:

```
import torch
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from transformers import AutoFeatureExtractor, AutoProcessor, AutoTokenizer, VisionEncoderDecoderModel, VisionEncoderDecoderConfig,AutoModel
from PIL import Image
class CustomVisionEncoderDecoderModel(VisionEncoderDecoderModel):
    def prepare_inputs_for_generation(self, pixel_values, attention_mask=None, **kwargs):
        # Ensure the pixel_values has the correct shape
        print(pixel_values)

        return {
            "pixel_values": pixel_values,
        }


def load_vision_encoder_decoder_model(model_path, encoder_name, decoder_name, max_length, num_decoder_layers=None):
    config = VisionEncoderDecoderConfig.from_pretrained(model_path)
    encoder = AutoModel.from_pretrained(encoder_name)
    decoder = AutoModel.from_pretrained(decoder_name)

    if num_decoder_layers is not None:
        # Handle the number of decoder layers based on the model type if needed
        pass

    model = CustomVisionEncoderDecoderModel(encoder=encoder, decoder=decoder, config=config)

    model.config.decoder_start_token_id = model.config.pad_token_id
    model.config.eos_token_id = model.config.pad_token_id
    model.config.max_length = max_length
    model.config.early_stopping = True
    model.config.no_repeat_ngram_size = 3
    model.config.length_penalty = 2.0
    model.config.num_beams = 4

    return model

# Replace 'path/to/saved/model' with the actual path where your model is saved
model_path = "final/"
encoder_name = 'facebook/deit-tiny-patch16-224'
decoder_name = 'cl-tohoku/bert-base-japanese-char-v2'
max_length = 300  # Replace with the actual maximum length
num_decoder_layers = 2  # Replace with the actual number of decoder layers

loaded_model = load_vision_encoder_decoder_model(model_path, encoder_name, decoder_name, max_length, num_decoder_layers=num_decoder_layers)
```

And here is my OCR class:

```
import re
from pathlib import Path
import torch
from PIL import Image
from transformers import AutoFeatureExtractor, AutoTokenizer, VisionEncoderDecoderModel


class OCR:
    def __init__(self, model, force_cpu=False):
        self.feature_extractor = AutoFeatureExtractor.from_pretrained('facebook/deit-tiny-patch16-224')
        self.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("cl-tohoku/bert-base-japanese-char-v2")
        self.model = model

        if not force_cpu and torch.cuda.is_available():
            print('Using CUDA')
            self.model.cuda()
        elif not force_cpu and torch.backends.mps.is_available():
            print('Using MPS')
            self.model.to('mps')
        else:
            print('Using CPU')

        print('OCR ready')

    def __call__(self, img_or_path):
        if isinstance(img_or_path, str) or isinstance(img_or_path, Path):
            img = Image.open(img_or_path)
        elif isinstance(img_or_path, Image.Image):
            img = img_or_path
        else:
            raise ValueError(f'img_or_path must be a path or PIL.Image, instead got: {img_or_path}')

        img = img.convert('L').convert('RGB')

        x = self._preprocess(img)
        print(x.shape)
        # x = x.permute(2, 0, 1).unsqueeze(0)  # Correct input shape for model
        # print(x.shape)  # Ensure the shape is [1, 3, 224, 224]
        x = x.to(self.model.device)
        print(x.shape)
        x = self.model.generate(pixel_values=x, max_length=300)[0].cpu()
        x = self.tokenizer.decode(x, skip_special_tokens=True)
        x = post_process(x)
        return x

    def _preprocess(self, img):
        pixel_values = self.feature_extractor(img, return_tensors="pt").pixel_values
        # Ensure that the channel dimension is correct (RGB)
        return pixel_values



    def post_process(text):
        print(text)
        text = ''.join(text.split())
        text = text.replace('…', '...')
        text = re.sub('[・.]{2,}', lambda x: (x.end() - x.start()) * '.', text)

        return text
```

I can create the OCR object:

```
ocr = OCR(model=loaded_model)
```

But cannot test on any images, even the train ones:

```
ocr('train_imgs/0.jpg')
```

The error I get appears to be with the shape:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/whalenlex/Desktop/jpdf-to-txt/testing.ipynb Cell 4 line 1
----> 1 ocr('train_imgs/0.jpg')

/home/whalenlex/Desktop/jpdf-to-txt/testing.ipynb Cell 4 line 4
     39 x = x.to(self.model.device)
     40 print(x.shape)
---> 41 x = self.model.generate(pixel_values=x, max_length=300)[0].cpu()
     42 x = self.tokenizer.decode(x, skip_special_tokens=True)
     43 x = post_process(x)

File ~/.local/share/virtualenvs/jpdf-to-txt-x2aoK0lp/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py:115, in context_decorator.<locals>.decorate_context(*args, **kwargs)
    112 @functools.wraps(func)
    113 def decorate_context(*args, **kwargs):
    114     with ctx_factory():
--> 115         return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/.local/share/virtualenvs/jpdf-to-txt-x2aoK0lp/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/generation/utils.py:1797, in GenerationMixin.generate(self, inputs, generation_config, logits_processor, stopping_criteria, prefix_allowed_tokens_fn, synced_gpus, assistant_model, streamer, negative_prompt_ids, negative_prompt_attention_mask, **kwargs)
   1790     input_ids, model_kwargs = self._expand_inputs_for_generation(
   1791         input_ids=input_ids,
   1792         expand_size=generation_config.num_beams,
   1793         is_encoder_decoder=self.config.is_encoder_decoder,
   1794         **model_kwargs,
   1795     )
...
--> 121     batch_size, num_channels, height, width = pixel_values.shape
    122     embeddings = self.patch_embeddings(pixel_values, interpolate_pos_encoding=interpolate_pos_encoding)
    124     if bool_masked_pos is not None:

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)
```

When printing the shape in `prepare_inputs_for_generation`, it somehow turns into `torch.Size([4, 1])`

However, when printing the shape in `OCR`'s `__call__`, it is the correct torch.Size([1, 3, 224, 224]). Any hints on why this is happening? Please let me know if there is any extra information that could be helpful.